# Find the number of $n$ such that $n!$ is a sum of three squares

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, integer-sequence

I want to check the following theorem by using *Mathematica*:

> $\textbf{Theorem} $. $\text{The estimate}$
>
> $\# \{n \le x:n! \text{ is a sum of three squares}\}=7x/8+O(x^{2/3})$
>
> $\text{holds.}$

(The positive integers $n$ such that $n!$ is a sum of three squares have a
density which is equal to $7/8$.)

I tried:

```
Solve[{n! == x^2 + y^2 + z^2}, {x, y, z, n}, Integers]
```

but there is an error message.

I want to do something like this (find the all perfect number from $1$ to $1000$)

```
Select[Range[1000], DivisorSigma[1, #] == 2 # &]
```

How do I find the number of $n$ such that $n!$ is a sum of three squares?

Comment: Make your search space bounded: `Solve[{n! == x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x <= y <= z, Sequence @@ (0 < # < 70 & /@ {x, y, z})}, {x, y, z, n}, Integers] (* {{x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 2, n -> 3}, {x -> 2, y -> 2, z -> 4, n -> 4}, {x -> 2, y -> 4, z -> 10, n -> 5}, {x -> 4, y -> 20, z -> 68, n -> 7}, {x -> 8, y -> 16, z -> 20, n -> 6}, {x -> 12, y -> 36, z -> 60, n -> 7}, {x -> 20, y -> 44, z -> 52, n -> 7}} *)` - this is not necessarily fast, but it works.

Comment: @vito This was a neat problem. Where did you see this theorem btw?

Comment: @ChipHurst "The Legacy of Alladi Ramakrishnan in the Mathematical sciences". page 243

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only care about counting and enumerating, why not use [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem)?

```
SetAttributes[SumOf3SquaresQ, Listable];

SumOf3SquaresQ[n_] := Mod[n/4^IntegerExponent[n, 4], 8] != 7

FactorialSumOf3SquaresPi[x_] := Total[Boole[SumOf3SquaresQ[Range[x]!]]]

FactorialSumOf3SquaresPi[10000]
```

> ```
> 8746
> ```

Or test your conjecture by subtracting $7x/8$ and dividing by $x^{2/3}$:

```
With[{x = 1000},
  ListLinePlot[
    (Accumulate[Boole[SumOf3SquaresQ[Range[x]!]]] - 7 Range[x]/8)/Range[x]^(2/3)
  ]
]
```

[image]

Or list such numbers:

```
Pick[Range[50], SumOf3SquaresQ[Range[50]!]]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
>   26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
>   45, 46, 47, 50}
> ```

### Edit

If we keep a running tally (instead of computing things separately), we can get results much quicker:

```
FactorialSumOf3SquaresPiFast = Compile[{{x, _Integer}},
  Module[{count = 0, m, offset = 1, prod = 1},
    Do[
      m = n;
      While[BitAnd[m, 3] == 0, m = Floor[m/4]];
      If[EvenQ[m], m = Floor[m/2]; offset++];
      prod = BitAnd[prod * m, 7];
      If[prod != 7 - Boole[EvenQ[offset]], count++],
      {n, 1, x}
    ];
    count
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];
```

Compare timings of old vs new:

```
FactorialSumOf3SquaresPi[10000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.57493, 8746}
> ```

```
FactorialSumOf3SquaresPiFast[10000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000495, 8746}
> ```

Here's timings on large $x$:

```
FactorialSumOf3SquaresPiFast[10^7] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.488944, 8751280}
> ```

```
FactorialSumOf3SquaresPiFast[10^8] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {4.8907, 87502143}
> ```

```
FactorialSumOf3SquaresPiFast[10^9] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {49.8406, 875001736}
> ```

Comment: It's annoying that `BitShiftRight[]` is still uncompilable. Otherwise, nice! BTW: I'd use `Quotient[m, 2]` instead of `Floor[m/2]`.

Comment: @J.M. I originally used `Quotient`, but this way shaved off some time actually. Yeah, too bad `BitShiftRight` isn't compilable.

Comment: Huh, would've thought keeping everything in integers would be faster. Oh well.

Answer (score 12):

Brute-force, but compact:

```
DeleteCases[Table[{k, PowersRepresentations[k!, 3, 2]}, {k, 10}], {___, 0, ___}, {3}]
```

> ```
> {{1, {}}, {2, {}}, {3, {{1, 1, 2}}}, {4, {{2, 2, 4}}}, {5, {{2, 4, 10}}},
>  {6, {{8, 16, 20}}}, {7, {{4, 20, 68}, {12, 36, 60}, {20, 44, 52}}},
>  {8, {{8, 16, 200}, {8, 80, 184}, {40, 88, 176}, {72, 120, 144}, {80, 104, 152}}},
>  {9, {{8, 304, 520}, {16, 200, 568}, {24, 48, 600}, {24, 240, 552}, {40, 104, 592},
>       {40, 272, 536}, {80, 184, 568}, {80, 344, 488}, {120, 264, 528}, {136, 272, 520},
>       {152, 400, 424}, {176, 248, 520}, {184, 368, 440}, {200, 328, 464},
>       {216, 360, 432}, {240, 312, 456}, {248, 376, 400}}}, {10, {}}}
> ```

For larger factorials, it might take quite longer; e.g. `Length[PowersRepresentations[11!, 3, 2]] == 126`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `PowersRepresentations`, good to know! (Assuming one actually finds other applications than snarky Mma.SE answers for it...)

Comment: It's a useful decomposition sometimes, but it does become combinatorically prohibitive very quickly.

Comment: @J.M. +1. but how to remove empty brackets from your result (list)? I want to find only  number of $n$, such $ n!$ is a sum of three squares

Comment: Just modify the filtering condition in `DeleteCases[]`, @vito: `DeleteCases[(* stuff *), {_, {{___, 0, ___} ..} | {}}]`

Comment: @J.M. I tried:   `Length[DeleteCases[Table[{k, PowersRepresentations[k!,3, 2]}, {k, N}], {_, {{___, 0, ___} ..} | {}}]]`    it works  perfectly for $N=11$, but for $N=20$ it doesn't produce a result even after a few hours of running :)

Comment: @vito, yes, that's what I meant by "combinatorically prohibitive".

Answer (score 7):

You can Try

```
Table[set = {x, y, z} /. 
          NSolve[{n! == x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x > 0, y > 0, z > 0},{x, y, z},Integers];
set = Union[Sort /@ set];
Join[{n}, set],
 {n, 3,8}]
```

This will give you how you can express a factorial as a sum of three squares. Now you can use further conditions (like $x\neq y \neq z$) with `Select` or `Cases` to filter them.